# 15 packages held back Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, held-packages

I can't updgrade my packages and 15 are held back. I don't know why this is happening.
This is my apt-sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012)]/ impish main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Hopefully this information is helpful.

Comment: you list your sources but not the command and error you get? How do you figure that is going to work? The "packages are held back" is a generic error See the proposed fix it states and if that does not work see @FedKad's comment but there are more of those. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: You don't let us know which packages are held back? Also `sources.list` usually does not show ppa which might be defined in `sources.list.d`. Best to see the output of `apt upgrade`. I had a few packages held back in the past days, but it solved by itself during another upgrade.

Comment: It's better to simply confirm that's really a phased-updates issue (maybe it is, maybe it's not). Run `sudo apt update`. Then please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421155/edit) to include the output of `sudo apt upgrade`. The list of kept-back packages will be at the bottom, but post the entire output anyway. Pick one of the kept-back packages and run `apt-cache policy <apcakgename>`, and post that complete output, too.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what command you tried; there are cases where `apt upgrade` cannot upgrade packages for example, which is why `apt full-upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` exists. Your issue maybe just user not using the appropriate command as we can't know without clear details as to what command you tried & message you received for provided command.

Comment: @guiverc I used the upgrade, full-upgrade and the dist-upgrade commands. They didn't work. I don't have access to my computer at the moment, but I'll get the rest of the informstion and update the post, if necessary. Maybe some solution was already posted here. I'll have to see.